# Opening new terminal window also switches to last tab

Tags: terminal, gnome

I'm using Gnome Terminal 2.31.3 and RHEL6. Like the title says, when I open a new terminal window, my current terminal switches to the last tab in its window instead of keeping the current tab active. It's quite annoying to have to switch back to whatever tab I had been looking at in the original window each time I want to open a new one.

This appears to happen regardless of how I open the new window: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>, File > Open Terminal, right-click > Open Terminal. (Although not when I manually type `gnome-terminal` in the window, but it makes sense that would act differently.)

Is this a bug in the terminal or is there a setting I can change somewhere?

Comment: This is the only implemented behavior. I'm wondering: what's your use case? Why do you open a new tab if you don't start using it straight away? Why don't you open the new tab exactly when you actually need it?

Comment: Perhaps I explained myself poorly. I do expect the window to now be in focus so I can use it right away (which it is). My problem is that in the original window, it will change from whatever tab I was on to the rightmost one when I open this new window. I want the original window to keep focus on the current tab instead.

Comment: For example: Window 1 has tabs A, B, C, and I am currently typing in A. Making a new window will have the effects: Window 1 now shows tab C, and Window 2 has been created and my cursor is in it. Second effect is expected, do not want the first.

Comment: This is definitely not the behavior of current gnome-terminal and sure never was the intended one. It must be a bug in that ancient version you're using.